# Node EJS - Cannot keep the data on form after submit

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs

I have following Server.js code

```
var result = null;
app.get('/reset',function(req,res){
res.render('index',{result:""})
})

app.post('/',function(req,res){
/* some logic... */
res.render('index',{result:some_value})
})
app.listen(/* Starting Server */);
```

Index.ejs

```
<form method="post" action="/">
/* 4 Text box for input */
/* 1 Text area for JSON output <%= result %> */ 
/* 1 Submit button */
/* 1 Reset button */
</form>
```

I am submitting 4 text fields from the form and based on that a output is generated which is displaying in the text area.

The problem is:-

1) I am not able to refresh the text area when I click the reset button as the output is from the server side variable.
2) I am not able to keep the form data, it refreshes on submit.

I have tried:-

1) Stopping the propogation on submit by specifying jquery  e.preventDefault().
2) Tried clearing textarea.

Could some one please help me with the same?
Also let me know if any further information is required for the question.

Comment: Can you show the code of the submit and reset button? if the `type` of your submit button is `submit`, you may want to change it to `button`

Comment: I tried that too. The post takes the control to the server post function. The post function has render index.ejs which re-renders the ejs file.